# Reducing length of table alias in Firebird EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, firebird

When accessing a condition column passes through several tables, for the joined tables generated a very long alias. In Firebird maximum identifier is limited to 31 characters. Is it possible to influence the size of generated aliases?

I use .net core 2.1 and FirebirdSql.EntityFrameworkCore.Firebird 6.6.0

Abstract example:

```
class Table1
{
    int id
    int value
    int idTable2
    [ForeignKey("idTable2")]
    Table2 table2
}
class Table2
{
    int id
    int idTable3
    [ForeignKey("idTable3")]
    Table3 table3
}
class Table3
{
    int id
    bool condition
}
```

When i do:

```
var result = Table1.where(t => t.table2.table3.condition).select(t => value)
```

generates query:

```
SELECT
    value
FROM
    Table1 AS "r"
    LEFT JOIN Table2 AS "r.Table2" ON "r"."idTable2" = "r.Table2"."id"
    LEFT JOIN Table3 AS "r.Table2.Table3" ON "r.Table2"."IdTable3" = "r.Table2.Table3"."id"
WHERE
    "r.Table2.Table3"."condition"
```

Is it possible to make the aliases of the joinable table as the main one? Like "a", "b", etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround. The code should be implemented by the Provider.

Create two classes: MyFbSqlQueryCompilationContext and MyFbSqlQueryCompilationContextFactory (see below).

Where you setup the DbContext:

```
        optionsBuilder.UseFirebird(connectionString)
            .ReplaceService<IQueryCompilationContextFactory, MyFbSqlQueryCompilationContextFactory>();


public class MyFbSqlQueryCompilationContext : RelationalQueryCompilationContext
{

    public MyFbSqlQueryCompilationContext(
        QueryCompilationContextDependencies dependencies,
        ILinqOperatorProvider linqOperatorProvider,
        IQueryMethodProvider queryMethodProvider,
        bool trackQueryResults)
        : base(
            dependencies,
            linqOperatorProvider,
            queryMethodProvider,
            trackQueryResults)
    {
    }

    public override int MaxTableAliasLength => 31;
}

public class MyFbSqlQueryCompilationContextFactory : RelationalQueryCompilationContextFactory
{
    public MyFbSqlQueryCompilationContextFactory(
        QueryCompilationContextDependencies dependencies,
        RelationalQueryCompilationContextDependencies relationalDependencies)
        : base(dependencies, relationalDependencies)
    {
    }

    public override QueryCompilationContext Create(bool async)
        => async
            ? new MyFbSqlQueryCompilationContext(
                Dependencies,
                new AsyncLinqOperatorProvider(),
                new AsyncQueryMethodProvider(),
                TrackQueryResults)
            : new MyFbSqlQueryCompilationContext(
                Dependencies,
                new LinqOperatorProvider(),
                new QueryMethodProvider(),
                TrackQueryResults);
}
```